# Xamarin: Cannot connect from Windows VM to virtual Android device running on Mac

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, adb

I am trying to debug my Xamarin Forms application using a virtual android device. This virtual android device is located on my mac (Pixel 3 XL, API 28, no play store, target Android 9).
In my VM (VMWare Fusion) I am running Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10.

So far I have tried the following to get the device added to the android devices drodpown in Visual Studio:

On my mac I start the virtual android device.
In mac's terminal I issue the following commands:
`adb kill-server`
followed by `nc -kl 5555 0<backpipe | nc 127.0.0.1 5555 > backpipe` in the `tmp` directory.

Back in Visual Studio on the Windows VM I navigate to `Tools` -> `Android` -> `Android ADB Command Prompt` and issue this command (while 192.168.1.123 being my Mac IP address):

```
adb connect 192.168.1.123:5555
```

which is followed by this success message:

```
connected to 192.168.1.123:5555
```

However, the device is not being added to the dropdown of available android devices to chose from in Visual Studio.

This command `adb devcies` returns: `192.168.1.123:5555      offline`

I am not sure what I could try so I can debug my Xamarin application using my Mac's Android Devices.

I followed [these instructions by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/connect-android-emulator-mac-windows), but maybe I have missed something obvious?

Comment: Can you please try running adb kill-server once more in the Mac to make sure the adb server didn't start back up over there as mentioned in [this comment](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/256375/#Comment_256375).

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT. I tried this but the device is still showing as 'offline' when running `adb devcies` within windows. When I run `adb devices` on my mac, is says `daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037[...]`.

Comment: Ok, I will try it later and update you if I find anything. BTW, you can use the emulator in Visual-Studio in Windows directly.